# Airflow Scheduler throws error for DAGs with schedule_interval as None

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have issue with airflow. There is a customer generator script which accepts input from yaml file and loads the DAGs. It works fine when all DAG yaml files have schedule interval as Non "None". There are many DAGs which has schedule_interval as None and few of them have @once.

YAML file example is -

```
cluster:
  nodes: 10
  subnet: "subnet-A"
  instance: "m4.2xlarge"
  configbucket: "bucketabc"
  jar: "s3://xxxxx.jar"
  conf: "app.conf"

schedule:
  state: "unpause"
  concurrency: 10
  startdate: "2050-08-05 00:00"
  cron: "None"
```

The generator script has below -

```
            if "schedule" in project_settings:
                schedule_settings = project_settings["schedule"]
                concurrency = schedule_settings["concurrency"]
                cron =  schedule_settings["cron"]
                startdate =  datetime.strptime(schedule_settings["startdate"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

            #print "my projectname is: " + project

            dag = DAG(
                dag_id = project,
                default_args=args,
                user_defined_macros=user_macros,
                schedule_interval=cron,
                concurrency=concurrency,
                start_date=startdate
            )
```

The error which I get when there are many DAGs with schedule_interval=None

```
INFO - [2020-04-08 12:30:45,529] {dagbag.py:302} ERROR - Failed to bag_dag: /home/deploy/airflow/dags/genertor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagbag.py", line 296, in process_file
    croniter(dag._schedule_interval)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.expanded, self.nth_weekday_of_month = self.expand(expr_format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/croniter/croniter.py", line 468, in expand
    raise CroniterBadCronError(cls.bad_length)
croniter.croniter.CroniterBadCronError: Exactly 5 or 6 columns has to be specified for iteratorexpression.
```

Did anyone face this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airflow DAG `schedule_interval` can either be a `cron` espression as a `string` or it can be `None` (NB not the `string` `"None"`).

In your settings you have:

```
cron: "None"
```

that is a string in Python. If you cannot change that YAML file to:

```
cron: None
```

you can still check for that string in the DAG itself:

```
schedule_interval = None if cron == "None" else cron
```